# DataGridView get current selected object

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to get the currently selected object from da databound DataGridView.

I do not need the object of the current selected cell, but the object on which the whole row is based, in this case a BusinessObject whos properties make the columns of the grid.

I could go over the DataSource, but that itself is just an object and can be a BindingSource or a IBindingList or something like that - so not easy standartized way to get the wanted object.

Behind that is the need to just check the businessObject for a property called IsChanged and ask the user to save or discard the changes, before the bindingsource selects the next item. Therefore I must find out the current object inside RowValidating-Event of the DataGridView, since the BindingSource does not offer an event to stop changing before change occurs.[See here for the well known problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/0921c331-8593-4827-80ad-4db6b0797f80/)

Thanks for reading ;-)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem` contains the 'business' object it is bound to.

Comment: Thank you for hinting me correctly, sometimes one should just lay back and relax instead of searching more intensly...

Comment: This is much better than caching the data and then trying to use the selected index. Thank you!

Comment: Just want to mention, that this also works, if your dataGrid is not 'bound' to the data, but instead if you just have applied it by 'DataSource'

Comment: See this for a Example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 7):

Here is my code put this into your Person class

```
 public static explicit operator Person(DataRow dr)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.adi = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        p.id = Int32.Parse(dr.ItemArray[1].ToString());
        p.soyadi = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString();
        p.kartNo = dr.ItemArray[3].ToString();
        p.dogumTarihi = DateTime.Parse( dr.ItemArray[4].ToString() );
        p.adres = dr.ItemArray[5].ToString();
        p.meslek = dr.ItemArray[6].ToString();
        p.telefon = dr.ItemArray[7].ToString();
        p.gsm = dr.ItemArray[8].ToString();
        p.eposta = dr.ItemArray[9].ToString();

        return p;
    }
```

and this is a update button click

```
DataRow row = (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
Person selected = (Person)row;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this short code.

```
Person selected = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Person;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this way?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  MessageBox.Show(item.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
```

We can get multiple selected rows data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did state the IBindingList - yes as others have said the DataBoundItem  property will give you what you need - there is an issue with it that I had experienced previously and ended up with a null reference but right now I can not think of the scenario in which it happened.

If you are databound using a BindingSource - you can capture the CurrentChanged, CurrentItemChanged events of your BindingSource , then you need not have an additional IsChanged Property on your B.O.  .. , also the underlying datasource could also indicate modified - for example if you have BindingSource bound to a datatable the row would give you a modified flag.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the selected cell value like this

```
yourDGV.CurrentCell.Value;
```

If you want the value in the form of a String just use ToString() method like this

```
yourDGV.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

This should do it