# i need declare a global variable named as celval but it gives the value of contentcell click

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void myDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender,   
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       {
           var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
   
           if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
           {
               string celval = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
           }
       }
   
   
       private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
   
           DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want delete selected Row?",
     "Important",
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
     MessageBoxIcon.Question);
   
           if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
           {
   
               string connetionString = null;
               SqlConnection connection;
               SqlCommand command;
               connetionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-1SAGJQ9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentEnroll;User
ID=sa;Password=sa";
               connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
   
               string query1 = "delete StudentDetails where id='" + celval + "'";
               connection.Open();
               command = new SqlCommand(query1, connection);
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               command.Dispose();
               connection.Close();
               MessageBox.Show(" Student Details Deleted Succesfuly !!");
               DisplayData();
           }
           else
           {
   
               MessageBox.Show("Please select a row");
           }
       }
```

[image]

Comment: This code has far more serious problems than the attempt to read a cell value in the wrong place, in the wrong way. It leaks connections and is wide open to SQL injection. Just imagine what would happen if that cell contained `'; DELETE TABLE Student;--'`. Using the `sa` login means nothing would stop a malicious user from doing any damage they want

Comment: You can [get the selected cell or rows using the correct properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/selected-cells-rows-and-columns-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). A DataGridView isn't a data *container* though, only a UI element. Its data should be supplied by *binding* to a DataTable or list of items. Instead of trying to read values from the grid, you can [read them from the selected data item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084976/datagridview-get-current-selected-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to declare the global variable celval , you can directly get it in delete button

for that you need to set  your DataGridView as MultiSelect = false; and SelectionMode = FullRowSelect;

```
    private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (senderGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
           string celval = senderGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells["yourColumnName"].Value.ToString();
    
           if (celval!="")
              {
                   // do your delete
               }
         }
    }
```